# Remount a network home directory without logging out

Tags: network

Looking for a means of reconnecting a network home directory without having to log out and back in. Unfortunately due to server maintenance or even sleep issues with the client, the network home directory connection is lost.

Comment: What OS(es)? What Protocol?

Comment: It is connecting back to a Windows 2008 R2 server over SMB.

Comment: 'it' is…. still rather shy on information...

Comment: Why can'y you just reconnect - i.e. click no the drive in the Finder sidebar (i.e. there is more info you need to give us on how you normally connect and what you can't do this)

Comment: Sorry, the "it" is a 10.10.2 box. The drive is mounted through directory services bind tool that allows you to specify the home directory as smb://

Comment: The drive only appears in the dock as a question mark and is not visible either as a connected or disconnected drive in Finder.

Comment: Are you connecting as ip/share or name/share? Is the sever guaranteed to win the master browser election every time? Macs over SMB are notorious for forcing an election & winning, when they shouldn't.

Comment: It's connecting to a name/share combination. My issue that the file server will briefly disappear from the network during server backups and then clients can be left with a question mark as their home directory in the dock. Starting to think this is unsolvable without a login/logout.